# JAVAFX : TextFieldTreeTableCell in FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

For a `TreeTableColumn`, does an equivalent of the following exist in FXML?

```
nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn())
```

Something like :

```
<TreeTableColumn>
  <cellFactory>
    <TextFieldTreeTableCell></TextFieldTreeTableCell> -> this doesn't work
  </cellFactory>
</TreeTableColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the no-argument [`TextFieldTreeTableView#forTreeTableColumn()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTreeTableCell.html#forTreeTableColumn()) method you can use [`fx:factory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements):

> The `fx:factory` attribute is another means of creating objects whose classes do not have a default constructor. The value of the attribute is the name of a static, no-arg factory method for producing class instances.

For example:

```xml
<TreeTableColumn>
  <cellFactory>
    <TextFieldTreeTableCell fx:factory="forTreeTableColumn"/>
  </cellFactory>
</TreeTableColumn>
```

However, this won't work if you want to use [the overload](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTreeTableCell.html#forTreeTableColumn(javafx.util.StringConverter)) which accepts a `StringConverter` argument.

Comment: hmm .. converter is a writeable property, so we can set it at runtime - or maybe even as value to the cell in the fxml somehow? Out of my home zone, though :)

Comment: I can't think of a way to set the converter via FXML. The problem being that the above describes a callback, not each individual cell, and you can't "intercept" the cell instances like one could in Java code. Of course, one could create their own no-arg factory method which sets the converter. But honestly, I feel this is one of those places where using FXML is more trouble than it's worth—better to configure these types of things in the controller.